# IOS: Updating Labels in a UITableViewCell using an NSTimer

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nstimer

I'm trying to create a countdown app that will show the number of Years....Seconds until an upcoming date.  I want to be able to view several countdowns in a table view.  I have some basic logic that works idependently of a tableview cell to create the countdown:

```
.
.
.
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "countdown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func  countdown() {
    let hourMinuteComponents: NSCalendarUnit =
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond
    let timeDifference = userCalendar.components(
        hourMinuteComponents,
        fromDate: NSDate(),
        toDate: date1.enteredDate as NSDate,
        options: nil)
// Sample Output
    println("Year: \(timeDifference.year)")
    println("Month: \(timeDifference.month)")
    println("Day: \(timeDifference.day)")
    println("Hour: \(timeDifference.hour)")
    println("Minute: \(timeDifference.minute)")
    println("Second: \(timeDifference.second)")
}
```

This works well and the console shows the countdown.  However, I can't get past an error when I try to call it from a cell.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer row]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here's the code that isn't working.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    println("Index Path: \(indexPath)")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("countDownCell") as! UITableViewCell
    let cellIndex = indexPath
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update:", userInfo: cellIndex, repeats: true)
    //let secondlabel = cell.viewWithTag(1005) as! UILabel
    //secondlabel.text = "Test"


    return cell

}


func  update(cellIndex: NSIndexPath) {
    let hourMinuteComponents: NSCalendarUnit =
    NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear |
    NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth |
    NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond
    let timeDifference = userCalendar.components(
        hourMinuteComponents,
        fromDate: NSDate(),
        toDate: date1.enteredDate as NSDate,
        options: nil)
    println("Year: \(timeDifference.year)")
    println("Month: \(timeDifference.month)")
    println("Day: \(timeDifference.day)")
    println("Hour: \(timeDifference.hour)")
    println("Minute: \(timeDifference.minute)")
    println("Second: \(timeDifference.second)")


    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellIndex) {
        let yearlabel = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
        let secondlabel = cell.viewWithTag(1005) as! UILabel!
    }

    secondlabel.text = "\(timeDifference.second)"


}
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.  I initially focused my fixing attempts on changing how I'm calling update() from the timer.  I tried passing the cell explicitly and then thought it better to try calling the indexPath of the cell.  I also checked my syntax as was suggested in a number of NSTimer posts.  I think I have it right (and believe I've tried pretty much all other options).

The code breaks at this line:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellIndex) { ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector passed to `NSTimer`'s `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(_:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)` receives a `NSTimer` object, not a `NSIndexPath`.

That is, your `update(_:)` method should be defined as

```
func update(timer: NSTimer) {
    cellIndex = timer.userInfo as! NSIndexPath
    ...
}
```

See the [method's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) for more information

Comment: Marcos - thank you very much!  That fixed my issue.  I had looked at the documentation.  I fear I always have a hard time parsing it.  But, re-reviewing it, knowing what I'm looking for, I did find this tidbit, which should have pushed me in the right direction:  "The timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the following pattern"

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend a different approach to how you've constructed your app.

`UITableView` will "recycle" its cells using the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method. So, if a user were to create 100 countdowns with your app, but there are only ever a maximum of 4 cells visible on screen, when the user scrolls those four cells will be enqueued into table view's cache of cells and then dequeued by your data source code. This is done to give performance enhancements so the table view scrolls smoothly. You can read more about this behavior in Apple's [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1).

If it were me...

1. I'd start by having an object that can track the state of a countdown: countdown start date, countdown end date, countdown name, etc.
2. I'd use an array of those objects to be the data that is represented by the table view.
3. Since *all* the countdowns update every second, you could update what's currently displayed by asking the table view what index paths is it currently showing, match those index paths to the countdown objects in your array, and then changing the text of all the different labels. This means you would only have one `NSTimer` instance in your view controller responsible for driving the updates.

There are plenty of other possible ways to structure this, but I *think* trying to manage many timer instances is going to cause some gray hairs.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent tip. 

That is where I sort of intend on going.  I'm very new to this and working to get one piece working at a time.  

I do already have the framework for an object that includes a description and countdown end date.  All the counters count from now till they end, then they'll expire.  

I was planning on populating an array with those objects and leveraging that to instantiate each cell.

Comment: Conceptually, I'm advocating for you to have one timer instance that is responsible for updating "the whole screen" instead of having many timer instances that are responsible for updating "this little part of the screen." I think as you follow the latter down the rabbit hole it will be difficult to keep all the timers organized, which could lead to strange and unexpected behaviors.

Comment: I think I understand where you're coming from.  By creating a timer with each row I can run into issues when that row changes.  For example, I just tried to delete a running row and the timer crashed, because it no longer had cells to reference.  I really appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly my point. I don't think what I'm suggesting is particularly easier to think about -- one timer to update all these things vs. a timer per thing that needs updating: the former isn't obvious. But, given how `UITableView` works, I think you'll spend less energy fighting against the building blocks. That documentation I've linked is pretty dense, but hopefully really useful for getting your head wrapped around table view.

Comment: @edlaney05  I'm too new to up-vote your guidance, but I sorted out having a timer instantiated on viewdidload() and then using:  
 `let cells = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows() as Array!`  
 `for i in cells`  
I'm able to update the data with one timer

Comment: Hopefully that continues to work for you as the project evolves. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

More simplistic approach will be to keep running your nstimer az it isvand call the countdown method and reload your UITableView at the end. Keep the values to be display in an NSArray everytime before reloading and pass it as object to UITableView.